# Why do singular propositions have a universal quantity?

Tags: logic, syllogism

Why do singular propositions have a universal quantity?
Singular propositions like *Amy is woman*.
Why do we treat them as if they referred to classes of things?

Comment: In origin, [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Basic_structure) was defined for [Categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) i.e. for proposition like "All men are mortal" withe "term" class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In origin, [sllogism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) was defined with [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) i.e. for proposition like "All men are mortal" with *class* terms.

The extension to singular terms can be managed considering the ["singleton"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) formed by the class containing the single individual: Socrates.

In this way, we can translate "Socrates is a man" as "Every member of the class containing only Socrates is a man".